# where can i found XEP-0054 Extension for XMPP ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xmpp

i am developing a jabber chat project with XMPP frame work.i heard XEP-0054 extension can be used for Vacrd Retrieval .Can any one say where can i found this extension?

---

I solved the issue .
we need to create a vCard Retrieval Request as per the [http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html][1]

[1]: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html link suggested and send it as XMPPIQ and if Vcard is present we will get it in `- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq`

delegate method

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can always dig into the XMPPIQ but why not using the XEP-0054 extension in the XMPPFramework. I think it simplifies your work and handles the hassel. It can be found under the extension folder ( XMPPFramework / Extensions / XEP-0054). The full implementation reference can be found in ([1](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/XEP-0054))